# Save the value from another function and check PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, return-value

I call again THIS function so I get some new $key is this and i want to add it to same array so I can check if it is same so unique it. Some thing like global array.

```
function getNodesInfo($node)
    {
               foreach ($result as  $key => $value)
                        {   
                          $items[]=$key;
                        }
                        echo ("-----."\n"); 
                        print_r($items."\n");

    getNodesInfo($subNode);
    }
```

It is my output

```
-------
Array
(
    [0] => author
    [1] => title
    [2] => genre
    [3] => price
    [4] => publish_date
    [5] => description
)
-------
Array
(
    [0] => author
    [1] => title
    [2] => genre
    [3] => price
    [4] => publish_date
    [5] => description
)
-------
Array
(
    [0] => book
)
```

and I want my output looklike

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => author
    [1] => title
    [2] => genre
    [3] => price
    [4] => publish_date
    [5] => description
)
-------
Array
(
    [0] => book
)
```

Comment: not sure, but maybe look at [array_unique() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: no it cant use array_unique

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Algorithm for this.

**Step 1 :** Create a Blank array.

**Step 2 :** Each time when you get an array with data, Check whether that array exists in the Blank array or not.

**Step 3 :** If it does not exist, Add that array(with data) to Blank array. If it exists Do not add that array just discard it.

At the end you will get the unique values inside Blank array which you have created. It is a simple process